# ng-repeat for ui.sref in AngularJS

Tags: angular-ui-router

Is it possible to print the menus with ui-sref using ng-repeat?

Pseudo code:

```
<li ng-repeat="menu in menus">
    <a ui-sref="{{menu.sref}}">{{menu.text}}</a>
</li>
```

Here, `ui-sref="{{menu.sref}}"` or `ui-sref="menu.sref"` is not working. `sref` is an attribute that exists in `menu`.

Comment: What it looks like menu.sref ?

Comment: menus.sref looks like "photos.list".

Comment: If I remember correctly, it should be key-value pair, something like: 'page({param: value, param: value})'

Comment: seems at least brackets are necessary: (), even if parameters are not necessary.